# Orbeon control details in own component

Tags: forms, orbeon, xbl

I'm making my own component, and I want to have oportunity to set some properties in form builder. In all I want to reach effect similar to autocomplete control, where I can set 3 properties (URI, xpath, and relative xpath). I read, that I can do it using control-details markup, but unfortunately it does not work. This is code (I working on davinci tutorial):

```
<xbl:binding element="fr|tutorial-davinci" id="fr-tutorial-davinci" xxbl:mode="lhha binding value">
    <metadata xmlns="http://orbeon.org/oxf/xml/form-builder" xmlns:xf="http://www.w3.org/2002/xforms">
        <display-name lang="en">davinci-modified</display-name>
        <templates>
            <instance label=""/>
            <view>
                <fr:tutorial-davinci id="" appearance="minimal" labelref="@label" xmlns="" resource="" >
                    <xf:label ref=""/>
                    <xf:hint ref=""/>
                    <xf:help ref=""/>
                    <xf:alert ref=""/>
                </fr:tutorial-davinci>  

            </view>
        </templates>
        <control-details>
            <xf:input>
                <xf:label lang="en">Some param</xf:label>
            </xf:input>
        </control-details>  
    </metadata> 

    <xbl:template>
        <xf:model>
            <xf:instance id="id1"><value/></xf:instance>
        </xf:model>
        <xf:input ref="instance('id1')" />
    </xbl:template>
</xbl:binding>
```

Answer (score 0):

You must have a `ref` attribute on`<xf:input>` which points to an attribute or element where the information will be stored. In [autocomplete.xml](https://github.com/orbeon/orbeon-forms/blob/085890d8937eed4052ae76e314867cf85c2037c9/src/resources-packaged/xbl/orbeon/autocomplete/autocomplete.xbl)`, there is in particular the`resource` attribute, which:

- [is pointed to by `<xf:input>`](https://github.com/orbeon/orbeon-forms/blob/085890d8937eed4052ae76e314867cf85c2037c9/src/resources-packaged/xbl/orbeon/autocomplete/autocomplete.xbl)
- [is present on the `<fr:autocomplete>` template](https://github.com/orbeon/orbeon-forms/blob/085890d8937eed4052ae76e314867cf85c2037c9/src/resources-packaged/xbl/orbeon/autocomplete/autocomplete.xbl#L48)